# Oracle procedure is not returning results when executing from script task on SSIS

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm executing Oracle procedure, which has three OUTPUT parameters and returns results in table type variable.

Here the limitations are, i should not use ODBC, MSDAORA providers to call the procedure. So I'm planning to using Oracle OLEDB provider.

I'm able to execute the procedure successfully, but when i do check (while dr.Read()) its not returning any records. But I know as per stored procedure results, it should return 66 records.

I doubt about my Vb.net code.... Please suggest something.. Thanks in advance.

```vb
    Private Sub GetClients()

      Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("PKG_HOBS.PRC_HOBS_GET_CLIENTID", FPP1_Connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    Dim p1 As New OracleParameter(":obus_grp_id", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p1.Size = 100 ' This is the size of items in array in THIS case
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

    Dim p2 As New OracleParameter(":ostat_c", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p2.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p2.Size = 100 ' This is the size of items in array in THIS case
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)

    Dim p3 As New OracleParameter(":ostat_msg_x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p3.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p3.Size = 100 ' This is the size of items in array in THIS case
    p3.ArrayBindSize = Enumerable.Repeat(500, 100).ToArray 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim oraNumbers1() As OracleDecimal = CType(p1.Value, OracleDecimal())
    Dim myobus_grp_idValues(oraNumbers1.Length - 1) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To oraNumbers1.Length - 1
        myobus_grp_idValues(i) = Convert.ToInt32(oraNumbers1(i).Value)
    Next

    Dim oraNumbers2() As OracleDecimal = CType(p2.Value, OracleDecimal())
    Dim myostat_cValues(oraNumbers2.Length - 1) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To oraNumbers2.Length - 1
        myostat_cValues(i) = Convert.ToInt32(oraNumbers2(i).Value)
    Next

    Dim oraStrings() As OracleString = CType(p3.Value, OracleString())
    Dim myostat_msg_xValues(oraStrings.Length - 1) As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To oraStrings.Length - 1
        myostat_msg_xValues(i) = oraStrings(i).Value
    Next

    Try

        MessageBox.Show(myobus_grp_idValues.ToString)

. . . . .
```

Package definition

```sql
 TYPE Tnumber IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
 TYPE Tmsg_500 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 

 PROCEDURE prc_hobs_get_clientid (
     obus_grp_id OUT Tnumber, 
     ostat_c OUT Tnumber, 
     ostat_msg_x OUT Tmsg_500);
```

Comment: what we should do now ??

Comment: Please check my final answer  - it works!

Comment: I made system.linq to get work. But still i'm getting this error. ***Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-01455: converting column overflows integer datatype*** Check my latest code in the question.

Comment: You are awesome T.S. I really want to thank you through out the entire conversation and assistance you made this to work. Awesome. You're genius. Thats what i can say...

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please up-vote the answer if not done so. Enjoy working with `.net/Oracle`. It was good question because other similar questions don't truly cover every intricacy of this ODP.net side. I think, both of us just learned interesting behavior. Of course, I would stay away from this complexity, if possible. But if you could simply open `3 ref_cursors` as output parameters and use `ExecuteReader` in combination with `Reader.NextResult`, or, created `OracleDataAdapter` and called `Fill` on `Dataset` - yes - all automatic with `adapter/ref_cursor`... you would miss all the fun!

Comment: Yes, I totally agree on your points. Finally i learn many things now. Going forward this will be my last issue on this code.`Dim oraStrings() As OracleString= CType(p3.Value, OracleString())
Dim myP3Values(oraStrings.Length - 1) As String
For i as Integer = 0 To oraStrings.Length - 1
    myP3Values(i) = oraStrings(i).Value
Next` Here i'm getting **Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleNullValueException: Invalid operation on null data**. why is it so? i know few records returning null/empty values. how do i rectify this?

Comment: On the bottom of my answer I talk exactly about this ->`If oraNumbers(i).IsNull Then`. I think, what you really should do is `dim list as new List(of string)(oraStrings.Length) ` Then in for-loop do  `If not oraStrings(i).IsNull Then list.Add(oraStrings(i).Value)` Then, if you want array, to `list.Toarray()`

Comment: Yes, it did the trick....  You're awesome again....  Master....

Comment: @ T.S. How to resolve ORA-01455: converting column overflows integer datatype? I am getting this error in vb.net while trying to execute an Oracle stored proc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `OleDb`, period. Microsoft tells you to use vendor-specific provider. Use Oracle's ODP.NET.

Second, to retrieve recordset from Oracle SP, you need to return `refCursor`.

**Edit:** At this time we know that your parameters are tables. To process this you need to add `p.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` to your parameters

Your code is essentially this:

```sql
Declare 
    obus_grp_id PKG_HOBS.Tnumber; -- numeric table value
    ostat_c PKG_HOBS.Tnumber;     -- numeric table value
    ostat_msg_x PKG_HOBS.Tmsg_500; -- string table value
BEGIN  
    PKG_HOBS.PRC_HOBS_GET_CLIENTID(obus_grp_id, ostat_c, ostat_msg_x);
END;
```

I see you executing anonymous block - you don't need to do this as this complicates things to you. What you need to do is use vb.net to execute package straight.

> **Bottom line:** your current ORACLE code does nothing to output results to .NET. Remove anonymous block and you're in business.

Here is the code to process your type of procedure (read in comments)

```vb
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("PKG_HOBS.PRC_HOBS_GET_CLIENTID", conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Dim p1 As New OracleParameter(":p1", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
p1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
p1.Size = 100  ' Declare more than you expect
' This line below is not needed for numeric types (date too???)
' p1.ArrayBindSize = New Integer(99) {} 
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

' Add parameter 2 here - same as 1

Dim p3 As New OracleParameter(":p3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
p3.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
p3.Size = 100 ' Declare more than you expect
' for string data types you need to allocate space for each element
p3.ArrayBindSize = Enumerable.Repeat(500, 100).ToArray() ' get 100 elements of 500 - size of returning string
' I don't know why you have problems referencing System.Linq but if you do...
'Dim intA() As Integer = New Integer(99) {} 
'For i as integer = 0 to intA.Length -1
'    intA(i) = 500
'Next

cmd.Parameters.Add(p3)
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

' Ora number is not compatible to .net types. for example integer is something 
' between number(9) and (10). So, if number(10) is the type - you get Long in 
' return. Therefore use "Convert" 

' Also, you return arrays, so you need to process them as arrays - NOTE CHANGES


Dim oraNumbers() As OracleDecimal = CType(p1.Value, OracleDecimal())
Dim myP1Values(oraNumbers.Length - 1) As Long
For i as Integer = 0 To oraNumbers.Length - 1
    myP1Values(i) = Convert.ToInt64(oraNumbers(i).Value)
Next

oraNumbers = CType(p2.Value, OracleDecimal())
Dim myP2Values(oraNumbers.Length - 1) As Long
For i as Integer = 0 To oraNumbers.Length - 1
    myP2Values(i) = Convert.ToInt64(oraNumbers(i).Value)
Next    

Dim oraStrings() As OracleString= CType(p3.Value, OracleString())
Dim myP3Values(oraStrings.Length - 1) As String
For i as Integer = 0 To oraStrings.Length - 1
    myP3Values(i) = oraStrings(i).Value
Next
```

**And this is Most Important part**

The most important part is how you fill your declared type. Lets take

```sql
TYPE Tnumber IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
v_num Tnumber;

v_num(1) := 1234567890;
v_num(2) := 2345678901;
v_num(3) := 3456789012;
```

This (above) will work. But this will fail:

```sql
v_num(0) := 1234567890;
v_num(1) := 2345678901;
v_num(2) := 3456789012;
```

And finally, this, will work with one condition

```sql
v_num(2) := 1234567890;
v_num(3) := 2345678901;
v_num(4) := 3456789012;
```

Here we will get 4 members in `p1.Value` but under index `0` you will have `oracle null`. So, you would need to deal with it here (if you have such condition)

```vb
' instead of this 
myP2Values(i) = Convert.ToInt64(oraNumbers(i).Value)
' you will need first to check 
If oraNumbers(i).IsNull Then 
. . . .
```

**So, the principal thing here is, WHAT is the index of your pl/sql table?! It needs to start from something larger than `0`, and preferably from `1`.** And if you have index with skipped numbers, i.e. `2,4,6,8`, all those spaces will be part of returning oracle array and there will be `oracle null` in them

[Here is some reference](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/OptimizePerfODPNET/OptimizePerfODPNET.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response T.S. Could you tell me what are the required namespace to execute this code. When i tried to execute, i'm facing couple issues. I used System.Data.OracleClient. Also can you Please update the code for getting the results from data reader as i mentioned above?

Comment: Yes,I understood your logic now. I agree reader is not require. I found ODP.NET provider dll file as well. When I tried to execute the package i'm getting the following issue. PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_HOBS_GET_CLIENTID'

Comment: This is the package declaration. TYPE Tnumber  IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  TYPE Tmsg_500 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  Inside the procedure, it will be like this PROCEDURE prc_hobs_get_clientid
                 (obus_grp_id            OUT     Tnumber,
                  ostat_c                OUT     Tnumber,
                  ostat_msg_x            OUT     Tmsg_500);

Comment: Hello T.S, As you suggested I have updated my entire code. But when I ran this, I'm getting some kind of error "OracleParameter.Size is invalid". I'm not sure from which parameter these issue is coming. Kindly help me out.  I updated my current code above, you can take a look.

Comment: I added size to code - try that (I just read somewhere `p1.Size`- max size). We're getting closer to resolving your issue - when I look at Ora docs - I see that they setting `ArrayBindSize` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1011933 Do you know expected size of array that returning? It seem that if you don't know exact size of table returning, you may need to set extra size to fit all items http://www.marcusoft.net/2008/11/odpnet-arraybindsize-and-size-for.html

Comment: You are providing the size for Int32 also, does it make sense? I felt odd, that is the reason i a asking you. And one more thing i'm getting the error on the line of code p1.ArrayBindSize = New Integer(99) {}. The error is "value of type 'integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of char"

Comment: Hi T.S, yes i am able to see we are very close to the output. I'm getting the following issue "ora-01455 converting column overflows integer". The first param output contains more than 13 digits as number "1900011273547". What I believe we have modify the int32 data type with some other? Check my latest code.... Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This is an integer only. So i set it as OracleDbtType.Int64. But i'm getting new error. ORA-06513: PL/SQL: index for PL/SQL table out of range for host language array. Sorry to bother you this much, I never worked on Oracle stuff. This is the first time.

Comment: yes, it will return only 66 records. i mean less than 100. Which size you are talking about? p1.size or p1.ArrayBindSize. where i have to increase the size?

Comment: read this http://psoug.org/oraerror/ORA-06513.htm - make sure that , even though you have 66 items, your index in plsql table is not greater than array top index in vb. In other words, if the index of your table is from 1000 to 1066, it is a problem , you need integer(1066)

Comment: What will be the namespace for Enumerable.Repeat. I think it looks like system.core. But In my visual studio  that reference is disabled. I'm not sure about the reason.

Comment: I was not able to add system.linq and system.core. Its asking like you need to have latest version to get this dependent dll's work. This is driving me hopeless.

Comment: I updated my source code with latest changes, when i tried to run this i'm getting the following error message. ***System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.***

Comment: Hi T.S, please find the latest code. Just now i updated.