# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible when calling Oracle stored procedure from Dapper ORM

Tags: .net, oracle, dapper

I am trying to pass an integer array to Oracle stored procedure.

following type defined in Oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPIDLIST 
AS TABLE OF Number;
```

following is the stored proc that is using the above type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTINPUTARRAY 
(
  IN_STR_ARRAY IN EMPIDLIST
) AS 
BEGIN
  --Doing something here.....
  NULL;
END TESTINPUTARRAY;
```

following is the code to call the stored proc from .net application using Dapper ORM.

```cs
List<int> values = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
OracleParameter parameters = new OracleParameter
{
    ParameterName = "IN_STR_ARRAY",
    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32,                    
    Value = values.ToArray(),
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
};
await connection.ExecuteAsync("TESTINPUTARRAY", param: parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

When the above ExecuteAync method is called, I get following error-

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible

I searched online about this issue, but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered one [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387136/1704458) before (you should examine it carefully, it should be your guideline as .net-ora dev) and this is what you need :

```cs
OracleParameter parameters = new OracleParameter
{
    ParameterName = "IN_STR_ARRAY",
    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32, 
    // -- ADD THESE LINES:
    CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray, 
    Size = 100, // Declare more than you expect                 
    // --
    Value = values.ToArray(),
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
};
```