# Retrieving TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) from stored procedure output in C#

Tags: c#

I would need your help at retrieving an Oracle table of `varchar2(4000)` as output parameter in C#.

I have this Stored Procedure:

```
Type TTABSelectResult IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;    
PROCEDURE FOO_Procedure(i_nIndex          IN NUMBER,
                        i_nAnzahl         IN NUMBER,
                        o_tabSelectResult OUT TTABSelectResult);
```

And this would be the code I tried:

```
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand
                {
                    Connection = Conn,
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    CommandText = "FOO_Package.FOO_Procedure",
                    BindByName = true
                })
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("i_Index", index));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("i_Cnt", maxCnt));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("o_tabSelectResult", ???).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var obj = (???)cmd.Parameters["o_tabSelectResult"].Value;
}
```

Could you kindly tell me which types I have to use? Because `OracleDbType` doesn't support something like `string[]`.

PS: I edited for further information.

**PPS:** Looking for a posibility to get the data out of the o_tabSelectResult table.

Comment: If you want a returned value then executenonquery will be the wrong answer - as thats more for delete/insert/update ..

Comment: Possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1728525/15498)?

Comment: thanks for your inputs, i added more information, couldn't solve this at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the output to an ref cursor, which can be used to populate an List in c#.

Works like a charm.

Thank you all for your input!